# Domain and Range of relations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having problems understanding how to solve/find the domain and range for these 2 equations.

1) $y-3x^2 = 2$

2) ${(x,y); x=3}$

Any help would be much appreciated, 
Thanks!

Comment: Is $x$ dependent variable and $y$ independent variable ?

Answer (score 2):

$(1) y - 3x^2 = 2 \iff y = 3x^2 + 2$.

$f(x) = y$ is defined for all $x\in \mathbb R$. So the domain is the set of all real numbers: there are no restrictions on the values that $x$ can take on. The range of $y$ consists of all values $y = 3x^2 + 2$. Since $x^2\geq 0 $ for all $x$, $y \geq 3(0)+ 2 \implies y \geq 2$.

$(2)$ Here, the domain is $x = 3$. That is, $x$ is defined to be $3$. However, since $y$ can be anything, the range is $(-\infty, \infty)$. This happens to be the vertical line (parallel to the y-axis) that intersects the $x$-axis at $x = 3$, consisting of all points $\{(3, y)\mid y \in \mathbb R\}$.